# Cosa significa "terragiolo"?

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Nel romanzo *Il sorriso dell'ignoto marinaio*, di Vincenzo Consolo, ho letto:

> Non digeriva, no, quella leggenda di re Ruggero, gonfiata ad arte dal vescovo e dal clero. Ché da quel voto e dal diploma poi del 1145, con cui il fondatore della Siciliana Monarchia dotava riccamente la chiesa, in suffragio dell'anima di suo padre il conte Ruggero e di sua madre Adelasia, il vescovo per secoli aveva 
>   esercitato ai danni del popolo cefalutano, perfino dopo la soppressione della feudalità, dritti soprusi abusi angherie e perangherie... (testatico sopra ogni animale da soma che carico di cereali arriva a Cefalù, dritto del macello cioè sopra ogni bove porco e ogni altro animale che si macella, decima sulla calce, decima sopra tutte le terre cotte, decima sulle produzioni ortilizie e sulle 
>   trecce d'agli, decima sulla manifatturazione e immissione delle scope, grana sopra legno e carbone, duodecima sopra vini mostali, dritto di dogane di mare e di terra cioè d'ancoraggio falangaggio e plateatico, decima sopra il pesce cioè sarde acciughe e pesce squamale, dritto di **terragiolo**, dritto proibitivo di vendita di neve sendo esclusiva dentro il palazzo vescovile...)

Sapreste spiegarmi cosa significa "terragiolo"? Non ho trovato questo termine in nessun dizionario ma, curiosamente, ho visto che appare in questo  [articolo di Wikipedia](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partinico).

Comment: Su un vecchio Petrocchi compare “terràgnolo o terraiòlo”, definito come un tipo di piccione, ma non sembra proprio che c'entri con questo. Evidentemente è un sicilianismo.

Answer (score 2):

Nel testo da te citato l'espressione "dritto di terragiolo" deve essere interpretata come "diritto di terragiolo".

Infatti da Treccani per [diritto](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/diritto1/):

> **diritto1** agg. e s. m. [lat. *directus*, part. pass. di *dirigĕre*
>   «dirigere»]. – Si alterna, nella maggior parte dei suoi sign., con la
>   forma più pop. ***dritto***, che ha inoltre alcuni usi proprî (v. dritto1).

Ho trovato in [*La questione dei diritti signorili in Sicilia a fine settecento*](http://www.storiamediterranea.it/wp-content/uploads/mediterranea/p3206/Rossella%20Cancila.pdf) di Rossella Cancila il seguente passaggio:

> In verità il problema doveva essere avvertito nella sua gravità e non
>   doveva costituire neppure un’eccezione ancora nel Seicento, se un
>   paragrafo della prammatica De seminerio, emanata dal sovrano in piena
>   crisi agricola nel 1646, era specificatamente dedicato alla
>   «vessatione che alcuni titolati e baroni inferiscono alli loro
>   vassalli, constringendoli a seminare per forza terre di loro stati e
>   feghi, assignandocile doppo della qualità e modo che a loro pare», e
>   impedendo loro direttamente o indirettamente di seminare al di fuori
>   delle terre del feudatario. La prammatica ribadiva il divieto di
>   coercizione, affermando il principio che seminare o coltivare dovesse
>   dipendere dalla mera e libera volontà dei vassalli,  che d’altra parte venivano assolti da ogni obbligo di
>   ubbidienza. Era però prevista una importante eccezione per quei baroni
>   che si trovassero «in possessione legittima di potere costringere li
>   vassalli a seminare ed ammaesarci le loro terre» o di riscuotere un
>   canone (**terragiolo**) da coloro che andassero a seminare fuori dai loro
>   possedimenti, purché essi fossero in grado di darne documentazione.

Il terragiolo era quindi una sorta di tassa o canone che doveva essere corrisposto in determinate condizioni dal vassallo al barone.

Comment: Scusa ma non capisco. Dritto di terragiolo è da leggere come diritto di terragiolo e nel romanzo mi sembra appaia come dritto.

Comment: Ho rielaborato la frase da te indicata. Spero sia più comprensibile.

Comment: Grazie, @abarisone, ma nel testo che ho citato l'espressione che appare è "dritto di terragiolo".

Comment: Ulteriore precisazione per il significato di dritto nel contesto in oggetto

Comment: Scusa, @abarisone, adesso me n'accorgo che non mi ero espressa bene nei miei commenti precedenti. Grazie mille!

Comment: Nessun problema, è stata un'occasione per rendere più comprensibile e organica la risposta.